# GitHub App token not working for GraphQL API

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api, github-graphql, github-api-v3

I’m writing a workflow to add issues/PRs as project items to the projects beta. I was previously using a personal access token for the GraphQL API call, which worked successfully. However, using a token generated from a GitHub App does not work. The API asks me to log in from the workflow -

```
Run item_id="$( gh api graphql -f query='
Welcome to GitHub CLI!
To authenticate, please run `gh auth login`.
```

I’m currently using [this action](https://github.com/peter-murray/workflow-application-token-action) to obtain the token from the GitHub app and set it as GITHUB_TOKEN in the environment while executing the query. Looking for a solution to resolve this, thanks!

Comment: Please create a minimal, but complete example that someone could copy and paste to reproduce the issue.